Django: How to use CURSOR .. WITH HOLD in Django ORM
In Django orm we have queryset.iterator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#iterator that uses under the hood Postgres cursor www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-declare.html in case we using Postgres as a database of course.
By default Django uses it with WITHOUT HOLD setting, which is default in Postgres, that why it is also default in Django.
Question is - is it possibe to use django iterator() with WITH HOLD setting (not default) without switching to raw SQL somehow?
Thank u

WITH HOLD is used when autocommit is enabled.
https://github.com/django/django/blob/adae619426b6f50046b3daaa744db52989c9d6db/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py#L427
Try to set autocommit to False
